# MCQ quiz is slow to load and randomization does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a MCQ quiz based on php and mysql. Here are the structures of my main tables:

quiz table: quiz id, quiz_category
category table: id, title...
questions table: id, quiz id, categoryid, title...
answers table: id, question id...

To start things, I have the tables populated with 150+ quizzes, 4 categories, 14000+ questions  and rightanswers for each.

To save time, for each question, the right answer is pulled from the answers table https://stackoverflow.com/editing-helpalongwith 3 other random answers .

Now when I was testing it with just two quizzes, it worked fine. But with 150 quizzes, several problems have cropped up:

- the database is slow and for later quizzes takes forever to load questions
- the randomization of answers is not working anymore - along with the right answer, the other options show the same entry, making it easy for the user to guess the right answer.

You can see the code I am working with in my previous Stackoverflow query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826573/randomising-questions-and-answers-php-quiz-not-working

Any idea about what the ideal queries should be for the quiz program to work?

Comment: Have you done some profiling to identify if the poor performance is related to the database (query's etc) or the application logic (loops etc)?

Comment: Having a look at your scheme and indexing would also help

Comment: Hi Steve, I am new to php programming. Do you want me to post the structure of the tables? Also, I posted the code that queries the database in my earlier post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826573/randomising-questions-and-answers-php-quiz-not-working

Comment: yes I did see your php code, but do you know if the PHP code is the cause of the performance issues or if the SQL queries you're running are slow to execute.  I would guess looking at what you index (or adding indexes to relevant fields) would help - but I need to see your database scheme in order to advise this.

Comment: Here is the database structure:

Comment: `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_title` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
`questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quiz_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
`quiz` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some tips on how to improve performance, however these will be generic and may not be complete.

From briefly looking at your PHP and SQL statements [from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826573/randomising-questions-and-answers-php-quiz-not-working), there are a few logical places for an index. To add an index please reefer to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more information

```
$sql4="select * from answers where question_id=".$row2['id'];
```

question_id should have an index

```
$sql2="select * from questions where quiz_id=".$_SESSION['quizid'];
```

quiz_id should have an index

Adding these two indexes will also improve selectivity on this

```
$sql3="select * from answers where question_id in (select id from
questions where quiz_id =$row2[quiz_id]) order by rand()";
```

This will help as previously you would have been performing a full table scan for each query.

Your other issue is that you have a loop and on each iteration you are sending commands to query the database, you should collect all the information at once before the loop and then iterate using that rather than sending individual queries each iteration.

Comment: I wanted to add a comment but it isn’t really related to my answer.  I would strongly recommend you learn about indexing and also joins in MySQL.  Profiling both your application and database will help you identify performance issues and also the root causes.

Comment: Steve, Thanks a ton for your Database tips. I am trying to learn all I can on the topic as the person who wrote the quiz is no longer available to fix it. SO, I have a database of 50000+ questions and answers but no code to run it on. :-) So, I appreciate your tips greatly. Thank you, again.

Comment: @user1589406 adding the index with the link I provided will help a lot. Changing the loop will also help too.  If this was the correct answer can you mark it as such to help other users. I can highly recommend the book "High Performance MySQL" by Baron Schwartz, Peter Zaitsev & Vadim Tkachenko